# Are lie group representations necessarily continuous?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm not sure that this is necessariily true from the requirements of a group representation.

I am particularly interested in this when it comes to constructing lie algebra representations from lie group representations. To do so by Taylor expanding curves close to th identity requires the representation of the lie group to be continuous.

Comment: A representation of a Lie group is assumed to be a smooth group homomorphism into a matrix group.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, there exist discontinuous homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}$ into itself, which would seem to be a 1-dimensional "representation" of the Lie group $\mathbb{R}$.  But as Berci says, continuity (or smoothness) is usually taken as part of the definition of a Lie group representation.

Comment: A representation of a group is a morphism of groups $G\rightarrow \text{Matrix group}$.. A representation of a Lie group is a morphism of "Lie groups" $G\rightarrow \text{Matrix group}$.. A representation of a topological group is a morphism of "topological groups" $G\rightarrow \text{Matrix group}$.. It does not make sense to consider set map between vector spaces, one has to consider linear map, which is more than a set map... It does not make sense to consider vector space map between Lie algebras, we have to consider Lie algebra morphism which is more than a linear map..

Comment: Similarly, it is not so useful to consider group morphism between two Lie groups; in particular, it is not interesting to consider group morphisms from a Lie group $G$ to a matrix (Lie) group $GL(n:\mathbb{R})$... Thus, depending on the extra properties of the group, the map we consider, when studying representations, changes... Observe that matrix group is a group, a topological group and a Lie group...